# Amortized Time Complexity Analysis of the pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Pseudocode:

```
for level_t in BFS_tree:
    for node1 in level_{t}:
        for node2 in level_{t-1}:
            Do operation
```

I am supposed to calculate the order of this code. Here is what I have come up with as of now.
The outer loop is a linear order (on |G|) loop. The middle loop is an n^2 order loop. Similarly the innermost loop.
Now I can't just go ahead and multiply this all because the middle loop is not n^2 over all the levels.
So, let Ai denote each level, Bi denotes the number of nodes in a level for the middle loop and Ci denotes the number of nodes in each level for the innermost loop.

Summation over Ai is n. Summation over Bi is n^2. Summation over Ci is n^2. I need the summation over AiBiCi.

How should I go ahead doing this? I thought of using AM/GM inequality but summation does not split over product.

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it’s most helpful to analyze this code not by counting loops and multiplying them together, but rather by seeing what the code does and using that to work out the runtime.

The first two loops, collectively, say “loop over each node in the tree,” and, for each node, that inner loop says “loop over the node’s children.” This means that we

- visit every node, and
- do work at that node proportional to its degree (number of children).

Overall, this means that the total work done is bounded from above by the sum of the degrees of all the nodes in the tree. And that works out to O(n), where n is the number of nodes in the tree, independently of the shape of the tree. A few ways to see this:

1. The sum of the degrees of all nodes in a directed graph is equal to the number of edges in the graph, and a tree with n nodes has exactly n-1 edges.
2. Imagine we do k units of work at a given node. That means that the node has k children. Push one unit of work to each of those children. Since each node has exactly one parent node, each node (except the root) has one unit of work on it after we’re done, so the total work done is O(n).
3. The pseudocode you’ve given above is equivalent to the pseudocode for running a BFS over a tree. Running BFS takes time O(n) on a tree.

Comment: The graph is not really a tree but any graph. So the bounds on the edges might change right?

Comment: @templatetypdef Excellent answer, much clearer than what i was trying to type out yesterday.

Comment: @Rider I’m not sure what you mean by “bounds on the edges might change” - can you clarify?

Comment: Nevermind I think I misunderstood what you typed. Thank you for your answer. I will accept it as the correct answer.